# Ubuntu Core 16 - pc gadget with serial console

Tags: ubuntu-core, console, serial-port

I'm trying to use a headless PC mainboard (APU2 from PCEngines http://www.pcengines.ch/apu2.htm ) with Ubuntu Core 16. It only has a serial port as console, no support for any form of graphics cards. 
How do I tweak the pc gadget to just use the serial port as console? On Ubuntu 16.04 you can do this during installation by modifying the grub.cfg file before the first reboot. How can this be done while building the Ubuntu Core image?

Comment: According to the information [here](http://pcengines.ch/howto.htm#OS_installation) you would need `console=ttyS0,115200n8` added to the initrd line for the kernel.  There is installation information on that page that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - and yes with the above initrd parameter I got the board booting with the proper serial port console. In order to do this, the only way I found was creating a local Gadget snap for the board and adding the parameter into the grub configuration file. Is there a more elegant way not requiring a modified gadget snap?

Comment: I really don't know on that one.  I work with servers everyday that need this console connection and we have to add lines to the grub for proper booting or even some of the servers will hang during startup until the proper settings are set on the initrd lines.